# I don't feel like I'm enough for my cat

Tags: cats, safety

I got a cat as a birthday gift (I knew about her a few weeks beforehand so I could prepare) and when she got here she stayed in my room. Immediately she used the litter tray and ate.

The problem is, though she does everything in my room (eat, sleep, play, etc) she doesn't leave. She's scared of everyone else in the house except for me, since I take care of her. She follows me everywhere as long as it's upstairs, and refuses to go downstairs. She's only been downstairs once. She's scared of the dog that lives here, and I'm scared to let her near the dog.

The dog has killed a kitten before and snaps at my other cat all the time, even injuring his face twice. He's not my dog, (he's lived here since before I did and I have no control over him) and his owners refuse to train him or get rid of him even though he's a blatant danger to the other pets.

I don't feel like my room is enough for her, I feel like she should be able to live in the house and have more spots to explore and play but I can't let her downstairs because of that stupid dog that they won't sort out.

She seems okay in my room and we play a lot, for hours each night, and she even plays fetch and brings her toys to me when she wants to play (which is the cutest thing) but I really don't feel like my small room is enough, and I feel guilty that I can't do more.

Comment: You can try some cat trees. Utilize the vertical space in your room. What's  there to put your cat's life in danger by letting her downstairs? Also try more toys.

Comment: Don’t feel guilty... Your cat is much better off in your room with someone who loves and cares for it than on his own outdoors.

Answer (score 6):

When you know that your cat is not safe downstairs there is no point in trying to do so. If your cat is happy in your room I see no problem in that.

If you are concerned that your cat is not getting enough space to play, you can buy one or two cat trees. You should try to utilize the vertical space in your room. Getting even more toys will make your cat more happy.

If you still feel that your cat should have the entire house as his own or perhaps some outdoor activity as well, you can opt for a guard dog. I recommend Great Dane. They are great for apartments as they do not need much physical activity and very little training. Despite the giant size and vicious look they are one of the gentlest pets. It is unlikely that Great Dane will ever attack anyone. Once you familiarize your cat and dog, the dog will be a great companion to your cat. And it's sheer size will scare away any potential adversary.

Again it's up to you. Go for Great Dane only if you want your cat to go downstairs or outdoor. Also you should be prepared for the extra expenses needed to take care of such a big dog.

[What Are Some Ways to Increase Space for Cats in a Small House?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11916/what-are-some-ways-to-increase-space-for-cats-in-a-small-house)

This question has good answers regarding vertical space utilization.

Comment: Maybe I did not understand you well enough, but buying a dog only to guard a cat seems like a quite foolish idea to me. A dog, regardless of its breed, needs at least two half hour walks and an hour training each day to be happy. Only buy a dog if you want a dog, not because of other reasons and prepare for the work!

Comment: A Great Dane can still harm or even kill a smaller animal; I've seen firsthand and heard accounts of accidents and incidents where a Great Dane was the attacker.